# How to achieve the same effect as slideIn (MooTools) for Jquery?

Tags: jquery, mootools, jquery-effects, jquery-slide-effects

Here is the effect I am after? Unfortunately, jQuery's `slideDown()` effect isn't the same. This is the effect that I am after (Code and demo is located at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSnKh/)).

I am aware that jQuery has an `animate()` method. But what exactly should be involved to achieve the same effect as MooTool's `slideIn()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to slide in and out (left/right) in JQuery, you should be able to quickly edit the code to match the effect you want:

----CSS----

```
#container_div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#inner_div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

----JQuery----

```
$('#toggle_link').live('click', function() {
    if ($('#inner_div').css('left') == '0px') {
        $('#inner_div').stop().animate({left: (-1 * $('#inner_div').width())}, 1000).parent().stop().animate({width: '0px'}, 1000);
    } else {
        $('#inner_div').parent().stop().animate({width: '400px'}, 1000);
        $('#inner_div').stop().animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

----HTML----

```
<div>
  <a href="#" id="toggle_link">TOGGLE</a>
</div>
<div id="container_div">
    <div id="inner_div">test in here</div>
</div>
some stuff to the right
```

Comment: it moves the div outside the viewable frame of another div, if you want to then set the container div to be invisible thats just another line of code

Comment: Thanks, this works! Tried searching. Wonder if there is a plugin for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsTYa/2/). It collapses the containing div so it does not take up space on the page while it is closed. This is pretty much exactly what MooTools does (not that I know MooTools but I did observe the CSS changes with Firebug).